# Lodash filter with custom condition

Tags: javascript, momentjs, lodash

I have following array:

```
  [{value: 0, label: 'January'}, ...
  {value: 11, label: 'December'}]
```

with all months which I need filter by quarter (1, 2, 3, 4) so when I have quarter 1 need months January, February, March.

Is possible filter this array for some range?
I tried this:

```
  console.log(_(months).filter(function(x) {
    return x.value >= 0 && x.value <= 2
  }));
```

Of course I replace 0 and 2 with variables, this is just example. Can you tell me why this didn't works? It prints lodash wrapper without filtered months. I also tried add on the end function *.values() but doesn't work as well.

I also using in my project moment library, so if exist simple solution with moment it will be also ok. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value()` function needs to be after the `filter` not the `console.log()`

```js
months = [{
    value: 0,
    label: 'January'
  },
  {
    value: 11,
    label: 'December'
  }
];
console.log(months);
console.log(_(months).filter(function(x) {
  return x.value >= 0 && x.value <= 2
}).value());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array of objects looks overcomlicated. You might use a simlple array of month names (as index equals the month number):

```js
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
function get_Q(n) {
  return months.filter(function(m, i) {return i >= 3*(n-1) && i < 3*n})
}

console.log(get_Q(1)+'');
console.log(get_Q(2)+'');
console.log(get_Q(3)+'');
console.log(get_Q(4)+'');
```

If you cannot simplify your array:

```js
var months = [
{value:0, label:'Jan'},
{value:1, label:'Feb'},
{value:2, label:'Mar'},
{value:3, label:'Apr'},
{value:4, label:'May'},
{value:5, label:'Jun'},
{value:6, label:'Jul'},
{value:7, label:'Aug'},
{value:8, label:'Sep'},
{value:9, label:'Oct'},
{value:10, label:'Nov'},
{value:11, label:'Dec'}
];

function get_Q(n) {
  return months.filter(function(m) {
    return m.value >= 3 * (n - 1) && m.value < 3 * n
  })
}

console.log(get_Q(1));
console.log(get_Q(2));
console.log(get_Q(3));
console.log(get_Q(4));
```